# Workflow for discussion board

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow, email, discussion-board

I'm trying to create a workflow in SPD 2010 whereby if someone responds / replies to a discussion board, it sends an email to the original creator of that thread.

I created a reusable workflow with content type message and set `To: Current Item:Created By`. But this doesn't work as it keeps sending the mail to the user who just responded rather than the thread creator

Answer (score 2):

- Create a Workflow Local Variable, say "`ThreadAuthorEmail`"
- Set up the Workflow variable like this:

  - Data Source: CurrentList
  - Field from source: CreatedBy
- Return field as : E-mail address.
- Field: ID Value: CurrentItem:`Parentfolder ID`.
- Use the local variable in your e-mail address.

Thanks to [Matīss Sīlis](https://plus.google.com/110411696533968892360)